# Flagging popup dialog, shows wrong question as duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, flags

I just tried to flag [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619381/getting-firefox-4-and-firefox-3-6-16-portable-to-work-at-the-same-time) as duplicate of [this question from Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/261296/is-it-possible-to-run-ff3-x-and-ff4rc-side-by-side).

But, when I started the process of flagging and came to the place to put a link, to the duplicated question, the system showed me the wrong question in the preview window.

**OR**, was this my fault to input a link that was not to an SO question in this dialog?

[image: preview window with an a possible bug]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, you cannot add duplicates from another site.

And indeed the number `261296` does refer to the question in the preview, but on Stack Overflow:

[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261296/batch-closes-prematurely-on-a-for-f-command`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261296/batch-closes-prematurely-on-a-for-f-command)

[`https://superuser.com/questions/261296/is-it-possible-to-run-ff3-x-and-ff4rc-side-by-side`](https://superuser.com/questions/261296/is-it-possible-to-run-ff3-x-and-ff4rc-side-by-side)

Comment: yes, i think this is the reason. But anyway it still will be good to change this behavior and do not show the preview if user input link not to the SO question.

Comment: True, @igor, but meanwhile Jeff has retagged this from `[bug]` to `[support]`, so I guess he does not want to waste time on that... You could change it into a feature request, if it is really important for you.